# Почему статус код разный?

Tags: python, requests, http-status-code-404

Вот ссылки открывается одинаково тоже самое, но статусы разные?

[https://yandex.ru/pogoda/москва/details?via=ms](https://yandex.ru/pogoda/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0/details?via=ms) 404
https://yandex.ru/pogoda//weathertomorrow/details?via=ms 200

Comment: судя по всему лишний слэш во второй ссылке.

Comment: Лучше у Яндекса спросить